# Find $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}x^{\frac{x^{\ln x}}{\ln x^x}}$

Tags: limits

$$x^{\frac{x^{\ln x}}{\ln x^x}}=e^{\frac{x^{\ln x}}{\ln x^x}\times \ln x}=e^{\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{\ln x}}{\ln x^x}\times \ln x}$$

I tried to find $n^{th}$ derivatives of $x^{\ln x}\ln x$ and $\ln x^x$ and use L'Hospital's rule, but I am stuck here.

Could some help solving this limit?

Comment: Hint :  $\ln (x)^x = x\ln(x)$

Comment: ganeshie: no, $\ln(x^x) = x \ln(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$y={ x }^{ \frac { { x }^{ \ln { x }  } }{ \ln { x^{ x } }  }  }\\ \ln { y= } \ln { { x }^{ \frac { { x }^{ \ln { x }  } }{ \ln { { x }^{ x } }  }  } } =\frac { { x }^{ \ln { x }  } }{ x\ln { { x } }  } \ln { x={ x }^{ \ln { x-1 }  } } \\ \ln { \ln { y } =\left( \ln { x-1 }  \right) \ln { x }  } $$